# Error while using AjaxToolKit Control 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Error Detail:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET
>   Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are
>   referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the
>   ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

How can i resolve this error ?

Comment: This is like the most descriptive error message ever.  If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing script manager. use:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager  ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<asp:ScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"/>
```